# Dynamic table for data input

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-sqlite

I am trying to create a grid scorecard. I would like the first cell of the top columns to be one set of data well call it the "location". the first cell of every row I would like to have the players names. Below is a crude drawing to help get the point across.

```
          | Loc1 | Loc2 | Loc3 | Loc4 | Loc5 | Loc6 | Total
```

---

Name1

---

Name2

---

Name3

---

name4

---

I have no problem creating a static form with a set amount locations and names. However I would like for the user to be able to add the amount of players. For example if they would like 5 players it would create 5 rows and likewise for the locations. That way I don't have too many or few rows.

Also when they enter a score how would I store it inside its own cell in the SQLite DB?

Comment: you want to know how to create/input data with that table schema above? The table you want would seem to be this schema: "create table mTableName (id integer primary key, username text, loc_one text ,..etc.. , total text)". Then use a tutorial like this to help you http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: try looking into a tablelayout. Probably the easiest solution. You could also make it look better with a GridView.

Comment: Alex, I have looked into the GridView. But i cant figure out what i need to do in order to display it to the user. For example one user may want to add five players and another two. What would i need to do in order for the user to only see five rows or two rows respectively?

Comment: If you do not care that a user can select an entire row rather than individual cells you can implement something like this simply with a ListView and custom list adapter. Use a linearlayout for each row with width=0dp and weight = 1. You will in effect form equal columns

Comment: I need to be able to add data to the cells. 1 cell per user per location. so for my example above i would need 24 cells to add data to for each user at each location. Once i have that i believe i can use a GridView to call the data and display the scorecard to the user in the format listed above.

Comment: Thinking about it could i create a table for the locations named locations, and when the user entrees the locations they have their own id. and for the users names create a table for each user labeled their name and create a default entry to generate a id so i have a cell to work with.

Comment: For example (working with my example above) i would have 6 entries for my Location table creating 6 different ids. For the users i would have 4 tables.(table would be their name) to get 6 ids to work with one for each location i could count the ids for the locations table and create the same amount if ids for each user table. That way i have the cells to work with and call to my GridView. Would something like that work?